# Meteor, how to change the way to hash password from sha-256 to md5

Tags: meteor, passwords, integration, md5, sha256

When do integration from an old system to a new system which base on Rocket.Chat, and Rocket.Chat base on meteor.  the old system use md5 to hash password, but in meteor is sha-256. Now I need change the way from sha-256 to md5 in meteor. Any thoughts, thx.

Comment: You can override the `accounts-password` package. Note, however, that you should avoid this and migrate your old system to a stronger schema, as md5 is considered insecure and offers nothing even nearing the security a babelfish implementation offers you.

Comment: @MasterAM Could you show me more detail about how to override the accounts-password. I tried to edit the file `~/.meteor/packages/accounts-password/.1.1.4.mol8zd++os+web.browser+web.cordova/os/password_server.js`

Comment: @MasterAM But when executing command  'meteor run', it can not be work. the command run failed, can't  pass compile process. even add a few useless comment , it compile failed. like this `While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.osx.x86_64):
   password_server.js:1059:25: password_server.js: Unexpected token (1059:25)`.  Please help , thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor accounts-password has a dependency called bcrypt with is more secure than md5.

Comment: How to switch to a new hashing type? Please tell the steps,thk

Comment: You have to get this `accounts-password` as a submodule in your meteor project and edit the package as you love to.

Comment: I really and sincerely appreciate for your help. But I still do not know how to solve it,can u show me more details.